# Dictionary brute force on DES encrypted passwords

Tags: c, homework, cryptography

For a school project I am tasked to decrypt DES passwords.  I have sample code provided below and I want to know if this is the best method. Also should I code in error handling for the dictionary file or does the `while` condition take care of this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <crypt.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./crack <password>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int n = strlen(argv[1]);
    char password[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        password[i] = argv[1][i];
    }

    char salt[2]; 
    salt[0] = password[0];
    salt[1] = password[1]; 

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/usr/share/dict/words", "r");
    char line[50];

    while(fgets(line,50,fp)!= NULL)
    {
        line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';            
        if (!strcmp(argv[1], crypt(line, salt)))
        {
            printf("Password found!\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("Not found\n");
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're keeping us in suspense — I'm dying to know which password matched!

Many password crackers also test for common character substitutions, e.g. o → 0, i → 1, s → $.

Other than that, the general technique seems sound.

I do have a few general remarks, though.

- What is `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` for?  Sometimes, defining it will change some of the functions you call.  However, it would only have any effect if you put it before your `#include`s.
- It would be good to make a function, even for a simple program like this.  I suggest that `main()` be responsible for parsing and validating the command line and opening the word list, calling `crack(const char *pwhash, FILE *wordlist)` to do the actual work.
- You don't close the word list if you find a match.
- Consider returning a non-zero exit status if the password is not found.  That makes your program more useful to scripts.

Answer (score 2):

The code is neatly-formatted, the variables are well-named, which is good.

---

I don't see why you have a variable named `password`. You only use for first two characters of it, to initialize `salt`. You could initialize `salt` from `argv` instead. If you want to have `password` then I recommend null-terminating it to make sure it behave like a C-string. I don't understand why `password` isn't of length `n+1`, why you didn't use `strcpy` or `strncpy`.

---

The salt is required to be 2 characters; maybe you should check that `argv[1]` is long enough before starting.

---

Do you have reason to believe that `50` is the length of the largest string in the dictionary?

---

> Also should I code in error handling for the dictionary file

Probably yes; because you want to tell the difference between:

- Failed to find password because word wasn't in dictionary
- Failed to find password because couldn't open the dictionary

---

Dictionary-based attack may be a fast way to find long, commonly-used passwords; but it's not the most reliable way (because if the word is not in the dictionary then it won't be found).

The school project might have asking you to build all permutations, for example [like this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/41510/34757).